# The number symbol in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

Can anyone please tell me what is the meaning of "#" sign in Verilog?

For instance:

```
counter <= #1 counterNext;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#(…) pound mean in Verilog?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16022898/97073)

Answer (score 1):

`#` is for a delay.  `#1` adds a delay of one time unit.  This is defined in the free [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) document in the "Procedural timing controls" section.